# cellranger mkfastq with full path to --id flag

Tags: rna-seq, 10x-genomics, cellranger, demultiplexing

I have always used `cellranger mkfastq` to demultiplex 10x genomics runs manually, though recently the commands to do so have been incorporated into a script that should call the `cellranger` whenever it detects that a run is finished (and can be demultiplexed).

The main difference when calling manually compared to being called automatically by the script is **from where** the commands are being called.

So calling the commands manually **from the directory where the samplesheet is and where the outputs shall be saved** with:

```
/home/ngs/installed/cellranger-3.1.0/cellranger mkfastq --id=demux_10x --run=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX --samplesheet=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/20200507_NovaSeq_129_Chromium_Anne_Fred_Samplesheet.csv --qc
```

does the job.

but now cellranger is being called (automatically) from `/home/ngs`. The error message that I am getting from cellranger is:

```
/home/ngs/installed/cellranger-3.1.0/cellranger mkfastq --id=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/demux_10x/ --run=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX --samplesheet=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/20200507_NovaSeq_129_Chromium_Anne_Fred_Samplesheet.csv --qc
/home/ngs/installed/cellranger-3.1.0/cellranger-cs/3.1.0/bin
cellranger mkfastq (3.1.0)
Copyright (c) 2019 10x Genomics, Inc.  All rights reserved.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/ngs/installed/cellranger-3.1.0/cellranger-cs/3.1.0/tenkit/bin/_mkfastq: line 531: __/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/demux_10x/.mro: No such file or directory
Martian Runtime - '3.1.0-v3.2.3'

Invalid name: /nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/demux_10x/ (only numbers, letters, dash, and underscore allowed)
```

According to the error message I cannot use slashes `/` in the `--id` flag.

Does anyone what I should pass to `--id` in order to get the outputs saved as
`/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/demux_10x/`?

I already know that if I just pass `--id=demux_10x` the outputs will be saved at `/home/ngs/demux_10x`. (again, I am calling the script that calls `cellranger` from `/home/ngs/`)

Obviously I could change to the desired output directory i.e. `/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/` and do `--id=demux_10`, though I am trying to avoid that for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `--output-dir` argument to specify a folder of your choice and use `--id=demux_10x` as before.

Comment: that works partially. All arguments passed to `mkfastq` were `--id=demux_10x --output-dir=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/demux_10x --run=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX --samplesheet=/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/20200507_NovaSeq_129_Chromium_Anne_Fred_Samplesheet.csv --qc`. The fastqs are being saved at `/nexusb/Novaseq/200507_A00154_0492_AHL72WDRXX/demux_10` while there is still a directory `demux_10x` and the file `__demux_10x.mro` at `/home/ngs` (from where the script was called). Hoping these files will be moved by completion of cellranger

Comment: The aforementioned files were not moved to the directory specified in `--output-dir`, even though the fastqs were saved there. On the `_invocatoin` file under `/home/ngs/demux_10x` there is an entry like `interop_output_path   = null,`, though apparently this cannot be specified by `cellranger mkfastq`. Guess the only solution will be to change directory back and forth

Comment: I remove quite a number of "such files" after my `cellranger count` runs, so this might be a deliberate design choice for some reason. BTW, the 10x customer service is very prompt, helped me in the course of a few hours in the past in case you would like to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error message is a bit exaggerated.  Try removing the slash at the end of your --id

Comment: tried that way too though it did not work